# How to get two fields using rex from log file?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm newbie with Splunk. My goal is take two or more fields from logs. I must check if one field is `true` and so use another field to make a counter. The counter is about how many requests is make by client using `user-agent` attribute.

My logic desired:

```
int count1, count2;
count1 = 0;
count2 = 0;

if (GW == true) {
  if (UA == "user-agent1") count1++;
  if (UA == "user-agent2") count2++;
}
```

At the moment I can get just one field and make a counter without `if-condition`.

This query works fine, and return the correct requests counter:

```
source="logfile.log" | rex "UA=(?<ua>\w+)" | stats count(eval(ua="user-agent1")) as USER-AGENT1
```

But, when I try get the second field (`GW`) to make the logic, the query returns `0`.

```
source="logsfile.log" | rex "UA=(?<ua>\w+) GW=(?<gw>\w+)" |stats count(eval(ua="user-agent1")) as USER-AGENT1
```

So, how I get more fields and how make `if-condition` on query?

Sample log:

```
2020-01-10 14:38:44,539 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-8] class:ControllerV1, UA=user-agent1, GW=true
2020-01-10 14:23:51,818 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-3] class:ControllerV1, UA=user-agent2, GW=true
```

Comment: Your log has a comma (`,`) between UA and GW  expresiions, your `rex` - does not.

Comment: Thanks @PM77-1. Solved the first problem, now missing use correctely `if-condition`

Comment: You do not need `if` just use `AND` in your boolean expression

Comment: I don't know how use `AND`. Where are I can put it? If the log have more fields like `UA=user-agent1, M=method, URI=some_uri ,GW=true, V=v1`. How I extract just 2 fields?

Comment: I posted my answer. Hopefully no typos.  As far as a different log format, you will need to enhance your regex or use multiple `rex` operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
source="logsfile.log" UA GW 
| rex "UA=(?<ua>\w+), GW=(?<gw>\w+)" 
| stats count(eval(gw="true" AND ua="user-agent1")) as AGENT1, 
        count(eval(gw="true" AND ua="user-agent2")) as AGENT2
```

If, for example, you do not know the order of variables or you have more than 2, you can use separate `rex` statements:

```
source="logsfile.log" UA GW 
| rex "UA=(?<ua>\w+)"
| rex "GW=(?<gw>\w+)" 
| stats count(eval(gw="true" AND ua="user-agent1")) as AGENT1, 
        count(eval(gw="true" AND ua="user-agent2")) as AGENT2
```

This could be a bit slower since `_raw` will be parsed twice.

Comment: Please, you can help me to improve the query to take the another format logs? Like: `UA=something, URI=something, M=something, GW=something`

Comment: Added 2nd solution

Comment: worked fine without use `UA GW` soon after source. Thanks.